# Updating ListView data in a fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I'm trying to update a listview in a fragment that is displayed. 
The button that has to update a fragment is actually a child of an ExpandableListView inside a NavigationDrawer.
For example: your have car names as children and as you click the child the CarName fragment gets displayed, it's ID passed to the fragment and the ListView gets populated with information from the database that corresponds to that ID. As you choose another child everything is repeated. 
I got everything working except the choosing the new child and updating the ListView inside the fragment.

Any ideas how that could be achieved?

Comment: I suppose you have access to that fragment from main activity, right? If so, why don't you expose a public method from fragment? And the method repopulates/refreshes the list.

Comment: Got it working, thanks for the suggestion, it was surprisingly easy :)